# Bootstrapping Spring Data Neo4j repositories

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am starting with `Spring Data Neo4j`, using `Spring Boot 3.0.0`.

Created application with `Spring Initializr`, added a `Node` and a `Repository`.

**Neo4jDemo,java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Neo4jDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Neo4jDemo.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Player.java**

```
@Node("Player")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    @Id
    private final String name;

}
```

**PlayerRepository.java**

```
public interface PlayerRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<Player, String> {
}
```

When I run this, It shows `Finished Spring Data repository scanning` message twice, with different repository count.

```
[           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Neo4j repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 123 ms. Found 1 Neo4j repository interfaces.
[           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Neo4j repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 Neo4j repository interfaces.
```

Am I missing something ?

Or just ignore these messages ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After adding following to `application.properties`, it shows `Finished Spring Data repository scanning` message, only once (with correct repository count)

**application.properties**

```
.
.
.
spring.data.neo4j.repositories.type  = reactive
```

I guess, earlier it was looking for both (reactive and imperative) type of repositories.